# Kernel Panic when using ubuntu bootable USB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, bootable

I am trying to reinstall ubuntu 20.04.
I am using bootable USB, but when I select [Try or install Ubuntu] I get the error in the attached image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93HPq.jpg)
I have Ubuntu 20.04 on this PC and currently cannot boot, so I would like to reinstall it, but I am having trouble doing that as well.

I tried bootable USB on all USB ports with the same result.

Comment: Hi, this question will get better answers in askubuntu.com.